# Question about rebinding names with decorated functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following scenario:

```
# module_1.py

import compiled_c_module as cm

cm.function_1 = decorate(cm.function_1) # decorate is just a decorator function
```

Then in main (or another encompassing module) I have the following:

```
import compiled_c_module as main_cm

main_cm.function_1() # Has the expected default effect of function_1

import module_1

main_cm.function_1() # Has the effect of the decorated version of function_1
```

I would like the decorated version of the function to only apply within the scope of module_1.

I realize that an obvious solution to get around this would be to simply assign the decorated version of the function to a variable that is local to the scope of the module (e.g. "my_decorated_func" within module_1), but I specifically would like to be able to call the decorated version of the function "as usual" after it has been decorated within the module while maintaining its default state elsewhere.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Why do you want to do this? What's the X in this XY problem?

Comment: Believe me, I do realize that this is not a typical use case ( and would generally be considered a bad idea), but I do have a reason for wanting to do things this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this in your module? Using `numpy` as an example:

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value

import numpy as np
np = AttrDict(np.__dict__)
np.sin = lambda x: x
np.sin(3) # Outputs 3 instead of 0.141
```

Basically, a `module` (e.g. `numpy`) is a (usually unique) object in python, while the variable name `"numpy"` or `"np"` is a reference to that object. When modifying `"numpy"`, you are affecting the only object, which will affect everything else that uses `numpy`.

By using `dict(np.__dict__)`, a shallow "copy" of `numpy` module is created, in which you can freely modify anything (in the first level) without affect anything else. `AttrDict` is basically a fancy `dict` where you can use syntax like `np.sin` instead of `np['sin']`.

Do note since this is a shallow copy, you cannot modify "second level" functions like `np.linalg.norm` (note the two dots), otherwise you still modifies global module. If you do want to, follow the same rule and create a copy of `np.linalg`

This will not affect the global definition of `numpy`, which means using `numpy` outside this module will not be affected. You can also force use `numpy` of this module outside this module by using `module.np`

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you! If you have time, could you elaborate on what exactly is happening here? Why does creating a new AttrDict object detach the underlying functions that are in the module?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It is somewhat complicated. But this do have some advantages such as you can "transparently" add some code without having to change the whole code base.

Comment: Indeed - but for such a simple need (only decorating one function in one given module), there's a __much__ simpler way - and doing a search/replace in one module is not exactly a complex task either.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the decorated version of the function to only apply within the scope of module_1.

Then don't rebind `cm.function_1`, quite simply:

```
# module_1.py

import compiled_c_module as cm
function_1 = decorate(cm.function_1) # decorate is just a decorator function

# then use `function_1` instead of `cm.function_1`
```

Comment: I do realize that (and I mentioned this in my original question). I have a specific reason for wanting to do things that way. @ZisIsNotZis's answer produced the result that I need.

Comment: I'm afraid I missed this mention when first reading your question. May I ask the reason for this rather peculiar requirement? I have to say I just can't think of anything that would require such a solution and suspect some XY problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to get defensive. I am working on a utility that improves the usability of a specific python api, and one of the goals is to make usage as familiar to users as possible, sort of a "set it and forget it" type of scenario (at least within a given module). It is possible that this is a direction with limited value, but it is something that I want to explore.

Comment: I didn't think your were "getting defensive", I was just curious about your concrete use case - and it makes sense so ZisIsNitZis's answer is indeed spot on.